# Linkable tabs in javascript

Tags: javascript

I've set up a page with a set of thumbnails that when clicked reveal content below. The content is all absolutely positioned and set to **display:none** and javascript changes this for each.

(I'm not very well versed in javascript and mangled this technique from this tutorial http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-create-a-slick-tabbed-content-area/)

Here is how I have set up the links:

```
<a href="javascript:tabSwitch(1, 19, 'tab_', 'content_');" id="tab_1" >
<img src="image1.jpg" />
    <h3 class="designers">
        Link 1
    </h3>
</a>
```

Where '1' is the number of this tab and '19' is the total number of tabs.

Here's the function code:

```
    function tabSwitch(active, number, tab_prefix, content_prefix) {  

    for (var i=1; i < number+1; i++) {  
      document.getElementById(content_prefix+i).style.display = 'none';  
      document.getElementById(tab_prefix+i).className = '';  
    }  
    document.getElementById(content_prefix+active).style.display = 'block';  
    document.getElementById(tab_prefix+active).className = 'active';      

}
```

Anyway, all works fine, but now I need to be able to have a URL to link to each tab separately and I have no idea how to do this with this setup (if indeed it is possible).

Will I have to start from scratch or can anyone help?

Comment: Start from scratch. `javascript:` URLs are no good. You should be linking to `#tab-n` or something and handling `onhashchange` and such. Why is the number of tabs even a parameter?

Comment: @minitech I guess he must be using it to hide the remaining tabs. Shouldn't be doing it that way, but thats what I think it might be used for.

Comment: It might also be helpful to give, say, the JavaScript code?

Comment: @DavidStarkey Schoolboy error - edited to include

Answer (score 0, accepted):

code snippet form url link for different tabs

```
 <ul class="tabs">  
            <li><a href="javascript:tabSwitch(1, 2, 'tab_', 'content_');" id="tab_1" >
    <img src="image1.jpg" />
        <h3 class="designers">
            Link 1
        </h3>
    </a></li>  
            <li><a href="javascript:tabSwitch(2, 2, 'tab_', 'content_');" id="tab_2" >
    <img src="image1.jpg" />
        <h3 class="designers">
            Link 2
        </h3>
    </a>
   </li>  
  </ul>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for this. Still confused though: if I wrap links in the <ul> class called "tabs" I still don't get how I could work out a URL to link to it?

Comment: sorry, but I don't understand how your answer helps. If I wrap the links in a list how will I then be able to link to them?