# Make link in javascript select tabbed content

Tags: javascript, url

this is a secondary question to the one I asked earlier this week here:

[Linkable tabs in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18235793/linkable-tabs-in-javascript)

I've made the below javascript work in terms of url linking - if i add #tabs-1 to the end of the URL the top section (jTScrollbar) of my page is centered, but I'm struggling to find a way to get the bottom content (the div id's with "content_x") to show also.

I *think* I need to trigger a click event? But anything I've tried has failed abysmally. As ever thanks for your help.

**Here is the code:**

Here is how I have set up the links:

```
<a href="javascript:tabSwitch(1, 19, 'tab_', 'content_');" id="tab_1" >
    <img src="image1.jpg" />
    <h3 class="links">
        Link 1
    </h3>
</a>
```

Where '1' is the number of this tab and '19' is the total number of tabs.

Here is the content that shows when a 'tab' is clicked:

```
<div id="content_1" class="content">
    <div class="modalBlurb">
        <img src="img.jpg" />
        <p class="Blurb">
            "Lorem Ipsum dum de darr"
        </p>
    </div>  
</div>
```

And here's the function code:

```
function tabSwitch(active, number, tab_prefix, content_prefix) {  

    for (var i=1; i < number+1; i++) {  
      document.getElementById(content_prefix+i).style.display = 'none';  
      document.getElementById(tab_prefix+i).className = '';  
    }  
    document.getElementById(content_prefix+active).style.display = 'block';  
    document.getElementById(tab_prefix+active).className = 'active';      

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"bottom content"_? A quick glance at your script seems like it should work, for all 19 tabs.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen by bottom content I mean the "content_x" div. The script works except when I link to #tab-x the tab shows but not the corresponding "content_x" div...

Comment: Even though you set `display` to `block`? Is there some other CSS that's blocking visibility?

Comment: It works fine when clicking the tabs, it's just getting a url that shows specific tab AND content

Comment: Oh, I see, you mean you open the URL `index.php#tab-1` and you want tab-1 to be shown? Get the `hash` by reading `document.location.hash`.

Comment: This is where i'm struggling. `index.php#tab-1` centers and highlights the correct tab, but the content block shows the the default and not `content_1`

Comment: I thought something like this would work:

    `if ( window.location.hash ) {
    $(window.location.hash).click(); //clicks on element specified by hash
}`

from [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11895681/jquery-if-url-hash-click-event-activate-javascript]

But no joy

Comment: `window.location.hash` doesn't have an `onclick` event. You can look at jQuery's solution, the custom `hashchange` event: http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/jquery-special-events/#add-and-remove-hashchange